# How do I float an element of a list that is read from a file in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, python-3.5

I am trying to find the average GPA from a file that I've opened and read as a list. The file contains student names, ages, and GPAs (2.8 for example) separated by commas with each student having their own line. I split at the commas so that `token[3]` becomes the GPA. When I enter the code, I receive the `Float object is not iterable` error. How do I float and/or define the string (`token[3]`) so that I can perform math functions like adding and dividing?

```
list=[]
f=open(file, 'r')
Sum = 0
for line in range(f):
    line=line.strip()
    token=line.split(',')
    list.append(token)
    print (sum(float(token[3])))
```

Comment: The error here is that you're calling `sum` (which takes an iterable collection as an argument) on a float.  It's somewhat unclear what you're actually trying to print.  The GPA value from each line?  The running sum?

Comment: The problem is sum()

Comment: please post some simple data, and even if you code work, why you just sum a float number?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (that you can hopefully extend):

```
import statistics

gpa_grades = []
with open('grades.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        gpa_grades.append(float(line.split(',')[3].strip()))

print("The average gpa is %f" % (sum(gpa_grades) / float(len(gpa_grades))))
print("The median gpa is %f" % statistics.median(gpa_grades))
```

Example grades.txt:

```
Bob,Smith,18,2.8
Simon,King,19,3.6
Jane,Doe,16,4.0
```

Output:

```
The average gpa is 3.466667
The median gpa is 3.600000
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I didn't think of floating the token in the append line.